# How do I populate google map using longitude and latitude values from SQL Data base and google map api

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

I am working on a google map project using asp.net web application. I am loading the location data from an sqldatabase. my backend code is vb.net. I load the data and serializes it and parse it to the front end as JSON. I then call the java scripts function from the backed to populate the map. the map works fine when I call the  method on page load event. The problem is I want to call the method on a button click event before showing the map but the map doesn't show up when I do that.

any help would be greatly appreciated. below is my code

.

my front end code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                  // Function to load the map and plot markers for locations
                  function loadMap(locationDataJson) {
                      var locationData = JSON.parse(locationDataJson);

                      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                          center: { lat: locationData[0].Latitude, lng: locationData[0].Longitude },
                          zoom: 16 // Adjust the zoom level as needed
                      });

                      locationData.forEach(function (location) {
                          // Split the combined latitude and longitude values
                          var [lat, lng] = location.SiteGPSAddress.split(',');

                          // Add a marker for each location
                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) },
                              map: map
                          });

                          // Add a circle for each location (example radius in meters)
                          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                              center: { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) },
                              radius: 100, // Adjust the radius in meters as needed
                              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                              strokeWeight: 2,
                              fillColor: '#FF0000',
                              fillOpacity: 0.35,
                              map: map
                          });
                      });
                  }

                  // Call the server-side code to load the data and then load Google Maps API
                  window.onload = function () {

                      // Replace 'YourPageName' with the actual name of your VB.NET page
                      fetch('Clientsiteaddition.aspx')
                          .then(response => {
                              if (!response.ok) {
                                  throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                              }
                              return response.text();
                          })
                          .then(data => eval(data))
                          //.then(loadGoogleMapsScript)
                          .catch(function (error) {
                              console.error('Error fetching or parsing data:', error);
                          });

                  };
              </script>
```

```
            <div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

```
 Protected Sub LoadMaps(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ' Dim connectionString As String = "your_connection_string_here"
            Dim locationData As List(Of LocationDataItem) = New List(Of LocationDataItem)()

            ' Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT LatLong FROM LocationData;"
            Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
                cn.Open()
                Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                        Dim item As LocationDataItem = New LocationDataItem()
                        item.LatLong = Convert.ToString(reader("LatLong"))
                        locationData.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
            'End Using

            ' Split the combined latitude and longitude values
            For Each item As LocationDataItem In locationData
                Dim latLongArray As String() = item.LatLong.Split(","c)
                If latLongArray.Length = 2 Then
                    item.Latitude = Double.Parse(latLongArray(0))
                    item.Longitude = Double.Parse(latLongArray(1))
                End If
            Next

            ' Serialize the locationData to JSON and pass it to the client-side
            Dim jsSerializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim locationDataJson As String = jsSerializer.Serialize(locationData)
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "LoadMap", $"loadMap('{locationDataJson}');", True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

// button click event

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        
        LoadMaps(sender, e)
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.tutorialspanel.com/integrate-google-maps-asp-net-mvc-using-vb-net-c/

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure that you have done your fair share of searching and researching first. After doing so and not able to find answers online, the community will be here to help!

Comment: thank you but the link does not address my issue. Besides I have also done couple of research but have not found the solution. my issue is that my code above works fine and the map shows fine when I call my method on page load event but does not work on button click event.